# C# open and edit .xls file right from stream

Tags: c#, excel, stream

How to open `.xls` file from stream?

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (CryptoStream sc = new CryptoStream(ms, new FromBase64Transform(FromBase64TransformMode.IgnoreWhiteSpaces), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
{
    sw.Write(base64String);
    sw.Flush;
}
```

I'm tryin to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop` but looks like its `Excel.Application().Workbooks.Open` method just starts the `Excel` application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading from stream You can use [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) package:

```
using ExcelDataReader;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (CryptoStream sc = new CryptoStream(ms, new 
FromBase64Transform(FromBase64TransformMode.IgnoreWhiteSpaces), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
{
    sw.Write(base64String);
    sw.Flush;

    using (IExcelDataReader er = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(ms))
    {
        while(er.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < er.FieldCount; i++)
                Console.Write(er.GetValue(i) + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, You might need additionally install [ExcelDataReader.DataSet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader.DataSet/) package.

Answer (score 0):

By library called [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) you can reach this by:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
    workSheet.Cells[1,1].Value = "Text in first row and first column"; // EPPlus index of columns and rows are from 1 not 0

    using(var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        package.SaveAs(memStream);

        using(var fileStream = File.Create("path"))
        {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh. Sorry then. However, I think that looks very similar to another library.